# F12 Jump to method -> go back to previous method after making the jump?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, editor

I can jump to code if I click in a method name and hit F12.  But, is there a keyboard short cut to jump back to the previous code editor location?

Comment: In Visual Studio Code You can also choose <Alt> + <Left-Arrow> to return to your original location after navigating using F12.

Comment: No. that doesn't work in VS2015.   Typical of MS to REMOVE useful and productive features.  (It as ALWAYS been Ctrl-* gojng back decades...  until those clowns decided to re-write it yet again)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> : (that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Minus) will navigate back (maps to `View.NavigateBackward`).

See [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) of pre-defined keyboard shortcuts on MSDN.

Comment: Note: use the minus key with the underscore character.  The minus key, on the keypad, may not work for this shortcut.  I suppose it depends on the keyboard that you use.

Comment: The shortcuts for more recent versions of Visual Studio are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 24):

@Oded is correct, but wait, there's more!

- If <kbd>F12</kbd> sent you to a new tab window you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to your original tab. If you hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you can cycle through tab windows
- In VS 2010 you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> to Go To Definition, in addition to <kbd>F12</kbd>.
- You can also hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move your mouse over identifiers to highlight which ones you can jump to

Comment: For F12, MSVS 2010 opens a new tab.  For MSVS 2013 it replaces current tab.  I'm not seeing anywhere to configure this behavior.

Comment: To Prevent Closing [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795944/how-do-you-prevent-visual-studio-2012-from-automatically-closing-preview-files)

Answer (score 14):

While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> are indeed the shortcuts to navigate to the previous/next cursor position, in this particular case (i.e., going back after <kbd>F12</kbd> or similar) this shortcut might be more useful:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> (=`View.PopBrowseContext`)

It will jump back to the place where you pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>, ignoring any cursor locations *after* you pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>.

(NOTE: currently using VS 2013, and hoping this shortcut entry also exists in VS 2010...)

Comment: It existed in VS 2010, and is what I've always used, but it doesn't seem functional in VS 2015, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks bro, this is really useful!  Seems to work fine on VS2017 CE.

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio 2015: Ctrl+Shift+8 (View.PopBrowseContext) to navigate back not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32097787/3258851)

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code, you can also use Alt + Left-Arrow to return to your original location in the source code after navigating with F12.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

`Alt + ←` ... navigate back

`Alt + →` ... navigate forward

On Mac:

`Ctrl + -` ... navigate back

`Ctrl + Shift + -` ... navigate forward

On Ubuntu Linux:

`Ctrl + Alt + -` ... navigate back

`Ctrl + Shift + -` ... navigate forward

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424367/how-can-i-navigate-back-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: These are for Visual  Studio Code. for Visual studio, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the top menu bar, right click and it'll give you an option -> 'command center'. See the arrow after you select it.

[image]