# Visual studio 2012 - is there a keyboard shortcut to move files from quick view to the open files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I usually click with the mouse on the "Keep open" icon.
Is there a way to do it with the keyboard?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Q, and type `"keyboard"` and press Enter to open the `"Options->Environment->Keyboard"` window.

In "Show commands containing" type **"Window.KeepTabOpen"**, then in the `"Press shortcut keys"` type your keyboard shortcut and press the `"Assign"` .

Answer (score 26):

Default Visual Studio 2012 keyboard shortcut for when your cursor is in the preview window:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

It can definitely be modified as [JMik describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670069/48700) but that will get someone going quickly. As well, you can also [kill the preview system entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12799031/48700) so that all windows open indefinitely and this shortcut becomes unneeded.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't find it in the German translation by its name but only by its current shortcut.

Comment: @ygoe try ctrl+k + enter to keep opened. You also can overwrite these shortcuts, searching for  "Open keyboard shortcuts"

Comment: @DiogoAlves This has already been solved almost two years ago. It's just hard to find it if you need to know the answer (the hotkey) in advance.