# How can I navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: If it's the usual VS keymap I'm used to it's Ctrl -

Comment: In Visual Studio Code that shortcut corresponds to "Zoom Out:

Comment: I think you mix up Mac OSX and Windows defaults here. CTR + - actually is the shortcut on OSX while CMD + - does zoom out there.

Comment: Use Visual Studio Keymap extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings

Comment: As of VS Code 1.28, you can go to the last *edit* location using `Ctrl+K Ctrl+Q` - https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_navigate-to-last-edit-location

Comment: @kimsagro Please delete or edit your comment. It is not "Zoom Out" but rather "Go Forward" and "Go Back".

Comment: @Andrew The default keys that View: Zoom In and View: Zoom Out are bound to are `CTRL`-`=` and `CTRL`-`-`, respectively. The `=` key is the unshifted `+`. `+` and `-` are the keys on the numeric row of the regular keyboard, not the keys on numeric keypad, which are referred to as `NumPad_Add` and `NumPad_Subtract`, defying conventional names as MS often does.

Comment: With a macbook with touchbar, by default there are two buttons (left arrow and right arrow) on the touchbar that navigates recent cursor positions, which is suprising but handy...

Answer (score 2212, accepted):

The *keyboard shortcut commands* are *Go Forward* and *Go Back*.

---

On Windows:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> ... navigate back

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> ... navigate forward

On Mac:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate forward

On Ubuntu Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate forward

Comment: I wonder why Microsoft decided to have different hot keys than regular visual studio.  This is very annoying switching having to switch back and forth.

Comment: Can you do this with your mouse? In other IDEs the back gesture/button  navigates back as well.

Comment: @RayLoveless It's maybe hard to switch back and forth, but it's super easy just to switch forth. Maybe they cherry-pick it to VS.

Comment: Kind of an annoying binding for windows, unfortunately :( Would've been good to have the same as visual studio.

Comment: Remap it to Cmd + [ and Cmd + ]

Comment: The left Alt+arrows didn't work for me on Windows (it did something similar to Ctrl+arrows), only the **right** Alt+arrows does what's expected.  Who knows what weird ThinkPad keyboard magic is causing that.

Comment: @RayLoveless VS Code is made by Microsoft so the Windows shortcut is the default. Alt+← is a system shortcut on linux and mac so they had to change it.

Comment: @Chris all of the keybindings are configurable. You have the power! :-)

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu. Vscode seems like a half-baked IDE. It's being a pain even to get some basic functionality to work.

Comment: I'd like to get the Windows behaviour on Linux. Is there a fairly easy way to change that?

Comment: @RayLoveless Are you sure for Linux? I use Ubuntu Linux Mint and Alt+Arrow is for me a way to navigate to the previous and next page on Nemo and Firefox.

Comment: searching `workbench.action.navigateBack` & `workbench.action.navigateForward`  under **Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**  worked for me, since I had an extension changing the default behaviour

Comment: and in 2021 not working in code on debian testing. So frustrating. Tethered to a mouse. set navigate forward and back to alt+left/right and it doesnt work. And no, it isnt a system keybinding.

Comment: I like the Windows shortcuts here, but I'm on Linux. Thankfully, it is easily changeable via Ctrl + Alt + P then "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts."

Comment: there is a plugin for this, (Code Navigation
) https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vikas.code-navigation , it is very useful. I don't understand why such a basic feature not added to the IDE.

Comment: It's better to support it on toolbar like Intellij

Comment: I changed mine to CTRL+ALT+- and CTRL+ALT++, so at least they would be symmetrical.

Comment: How to navigate view back and forth and not location ?

Comment: @rynop There is also a default mapping to the next / previous thumb buttons on the mouse. These shortcuts are very useful when working on a laptop touchpad or a mouse without side buttons.

Comment: Where is difference between **Back** / **Forward** and **Last Edit Location**?

Comment: accidental downvote; sorry!  corrected to upvote

Answer (score 135):

I am on Mac OS X, so I can't answer for Windows users:

I added a custom keymap entry and set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>, while the original default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (which translates to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ß</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ß</kbd> on my German keyboard).

One can simply modify it in the user keymap settings:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+left",  "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack" },
{ "key": "ctrl+right", "command": "workbench.action.navigateForward" }
```

For the accepted answer I actually wonder. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> jumps wordwise for me (which is kind of standard in all editors). Did they really do this mapping for the Windows version?

Comment: `Ctrl+Left` and `Ctrl+Right` are reserved for switching between full-screens, aren't they?

Comment: @duong_dajgja I have that on Ctrl+Option+Command Left / Right. Most people will usually just use the three finger wipe on their Trackpad. I am not sure whats the "original" default in a fresh installed OS X Sierra though. At least there is nothing reserved in OS X. You can easily change that in the system preferences "keyboard -> mission control".

Comment: Use this to make those changes https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: Is there a way I can assign my mouse forward and backward buttons to navigate?

Comment: As @duong_dajgja pointed out this key combination is reserved. I used `ctrl+shift+left` instead.

Comment: Great answer. Also you can find it through  *File → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts* then searching *Go Back* and *Go Forward*

Answer (score 117):

This will be different for each OS, based on the information in *[Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)*.

#### Workbench configuration:

Go Back: workbench.action.navigateBack 
Go Forward: workbench.action.navigateForward

#### Linux:

Go Back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> 
Go Forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

#### Mac OS X:

Go Back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> 
Go Forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift (⇧)</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

#### Windows:

Go Back: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⬅️</kbd> 
Go Forward: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>➡️</kbd>

Comment: I'm using linux and the default keymap didn't work. I modified to Alt+Left and worked like a charm.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: `File/preferences/Keyboard shortcut [Ctrl-K Ctrl-S]` then search "workbench.action.navigateBack". Had to set it on Linux.

Answer (score 30):

To answer for your question, for:

1. Windows use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for backward, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> for forward navigation.
2. macOS use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for backward, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for forward navigation.
3. Linux use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for backward, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for forward navigation.

You can find the current key-bindings in "[Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor)."

You can even edit the key-binding as per your preference.

Comment: You have switched windows and mac bindings.

Comment: as perrier said you have switched the window and mac

Answer (score 23):

There is an extension available named [Code-Navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vikas.code-navigation) for all the platforms. As an alternative to the keyboard shortcuts it adds buttons to the left side of the status bar.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best answer among all the answers in here

Comment: briliant nice ext !!!

Comment: Apparently now this is built into VSCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75892641/399435

Comment: Good call @KarthicRaghupathi I didn't even notice!

Answer (score 17):

To set your own keyboard shortcuts (even if that particular keyboard-combo is already taken) you can go to `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` and set them up there.

1. Open Settings: `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`
2. Find `Go Forward` and `Go Back` and set them to whatever you like.
3. If a key shortcut is double-assigned VSCode will tell you, and you can click-in and change/remove the other ones. eg. by shortcuts were already assigned to indent-in and indent-out.

[image: gif showing the process of setting up the new keyboard shortcuts]

eg. our main tool is Android Studio on a mac which uses <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for forward and backward). This is especially powerful with a <kbd>cmd</kbd>+click for drilling into functions. (so you can follow your code as if it was an Ariadne's thread in a Minotaur labyrinth. Does help! ( so you jump around the code, diving in and out of functions, and back between files.

Answer (score 16):

For macOS:

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>: Undo the last cursor operation

You can also try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

BTW, all the shortcuts are in *[Keyboard shortcuts for macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)*. This is really useful!

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! While all the others actually tell you how to navigate back and forth through different files, I was interested in navigating the cursor history.

You could add (although it's kinda obvious) that there's the redo cursor operation to go with it.

Answer (score 9):

vscode v1.65 is adding a number of new commands for navigating to the last/next edit location or the last/next cursor location.

An `edit location` means there was an actual edit, whereas a `cursor location` means that you visited that location but may not necessarily have made an edit there.

> By default, editor navigation locations are added whenever you
> navigate across editors but also when navigating within editors (for
> example, when switching notebook cells or changing selection in text
> editors). If you feel that too many locations are being recorded, new
> commands have been added that reduce locations to either:
>
> - Navigation locations (for example when using Go to Definition)
> - Edit locations (whenever an editor is changed, for example when typing in a text editor)

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_65.md

#### Cursor locations:

```
Go Forward in Navigation Locations
"workbench.action.navigateForwardInNavigationLocations"

Go Back in Navigation Locations
"workbench.action.navigateBackInNavigationLocations"

Go to Last Navigation Location
      // acts like a toggle between current and last cursor location
"workbench.action.navigateToLastNavigationLocation"

Go Previous in Navigation Locations
"workbench.action.navigatePreviousInNavigationLocations"
```

#### Edit locations:

```
Go Forward in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigateForwardInEditLocations"

Go Back in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigateBackInEditLocations"

Go Previous in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigatePreviousInEditLocations"

Go to Last Edit Location
      // acts like a toggle between current and last edit location
"workbench.action.navigateToLastEditLocation"
```

> Associated context keys have been added to make assigning keybindings
> more powerful:
>
> - `canNavigateBackInNavigationLocations`: Whether it is possible to go back in navigation locations
> - `canNavigateForwardInNavigationLocations`: Whether it is possible to go forward in navigation locations
> - `canNavigateToLastNavigationLocation`: Whether it is possible to go to the last navigation location
> - `canNavigateBackInEditLocations`: Whether it is possible to go back in edit locations
> - `canNavigateForwardInEditLocations`: Whether it is possible to go forward in edit locations
> - `canNavigateToLastEditLocation`: Whether it is possible to go to the last edit location

Answer (score 8):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>→</kbd>

You can find all shortcuts in *[Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)*.

Answer (score 8):

Mac OS ([MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro)):

Back: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(control) + <kbd>-</kbd> (hyphen)

Back forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (hyphen)

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the keyboard shortcuts, there is an extension named "[Back and Forward buttons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=grimmer.vscode-back-forward-button)" that adds the forward and back buttons to the status bar.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*. Once you are there, you can **search for *navigate***. Then, you will see all shortcuts set for your Visual Studio Code environment related to navigation. In my case, it was only <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to get my cursor back.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `-` on Linux (Visual Studio Code 1.54.3 on [Ubuntu MATE&nbsp;20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa)).

Answer (score 4):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433087/925478) is correct, anyone using the [Vim extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) may be frustrated by the fact that navigating backwards takes you through *every single cursor movement you've made*. This prevents "Go back" from working well for use cases like:

1. Go to Definition
2. Poke around at the definition for a while (i.e., move the cursor around)
3. Go Back to where you were in step 1.

With the Vim extension installed, you'll be stuck doing "Go Back" for every cursor movement you've made (and for me, that's enough to make it almost useless!).

Fortunately, the Vim extension implements [jumplists](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations) well, so after using VS Code to jump to a new position (i.e., "Go to definition"), you can simply do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to go back to the previous jump location.

Answer (score 4):

## Last Edit Position v. Last Navigation Position

### Go To Last Edit Position:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>

This was mentioned in [sudormfbin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7115678/sudormrfbin)'s comment but not listed as an answer. This is what I want to do 99% of the time when I think "where was I now?". It is the easiest quickest way to get back to your last position without taking your fingers off keyboard to use the arrow keys and without installing extensions, etc.

### Navigate Recent Cursor Positions:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>←</kbd>  Back

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Forward

Most of the other posted solutions refer to this - moving between   "Navigation Locations", i.e., navigating between editor tabs OR within an editor (e.g., you move the cursor on one line, then click on a line 20 spaces above).

For navigating between editor tabs, instead of the above you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as it will sort all of the tabs in most recent order so you have option to go to others or just release and go back to the last used one. Also without taking fingers off keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

With [Visual Studio Code 1.43 (Q1 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7415295786638654d08e2a88c41e737b803edb89/release-notes/v1_43.md#notable-fixes), those <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> will also... **preserve selection**.

See [issue 89699](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/89699):

[Benjamin Pasero (`bpasero`)](https://github.com/bpasero) adds:

> **going back/forward restores selections as they were**.
>
> Note that in order to get a history entry there needs to be at least 10 lines between the positions to consider the entry as new entry.

[image: Go back/Forward selection -- https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/900690/73729489-6ca7da80-4735-11ea-9345-1228f0302110.gif]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go back and options to go back in vs code.

To change any of the following things, go to command pannel by pressing `ctrl` + `p` and then after typing a `>`, type what config you need to change:

[image]

Then all you need to do is click on the Settings icon (as pointed by 2 in the image) and change the key binding to whatever you want.

Different options you have for going back:

1. Go to the Last Edit Location
2. Cursor Undo `(meaning: go to last cursor location)`
3. Cursor Redo `(Opposite of above)`

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can also define your own keybindings for navigation

```json
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateForward",
        "key": "cmd+alt+[ArrowRight]"
    },
    {
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack",
        "key": "cmd+alt+[ArrowLeft]"
    },
```