# Go to definition and back to reference in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently using VSCode and am trying to use the <kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut which takes me to a definition of an object/function. When I want to go back to the reference, I can't seem to find the right way to do it. With VS community I used <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

I've try different combinations, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> but all I get is a peek definition of the element which is not useful at all; it's just a popup showing the same element in the same file I'm at. I've seen answers to this question but pertaining to VS 2010 which are no longer applicable or doesn't work with VSCode.

**Question**: What is the shortcut to Go Back once you've used <kbd>F12</kbd> to Go to the definition?

Comment: Adjacently related: [How I can make `ctrl + click` to go to definition in visual studio code editor for mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57446936/4561887)

Answer (score 182):

For macOS it is `⌃-` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>) by default. And for Windows: (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>)

Comment: (Alt + LeftArrow) does not work on Windows

Comment: If it doesn't go to vscode setting then shortcuts. Search for `Go Back` command and bind it with `Alt` + `LeftArrow`. For it was default setting.

Comment: this works on macOS

Answer (score 43):

According to the vscode [keyboard shortcuts documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings), the navigateBack action defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

In my keybindings.json file, I've rebound it to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> using:

`{ "key": "ctrl+-", "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack" }`

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that takes you back/forward to where your cursor/highlight text was last, as opposed to toggling between object and definition.

Answer (score 25):

You can open the `Keyboard Shortcuts` to find the shortcuts.

> Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Search for `Go`, and it’ll show the `Go Back` and `Go Forward` shortcuts.

In macOS:

**Go Back**: <kbd>⌃-</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)

**Go Forward**: <kbd>⌃⇧-</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>)

```
[
  {
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack",
    "key": "ctrl+-"
  },
  {
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateForward",
    "key": "ctrl+shift+-"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> should be working for you. There is a box on the right of the peek view which lists all the references. You are seeing the peek view to the reference you went to (the definition) but on the right are more. That boundary between the two can be dragged left and right so perhaps yours is not visible - trying dragging the peek view box right boundary to the left after you hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>. Do you see a list of references there?  Double-clicking the one you started from originally will take you back to it.

**Edit:**

`v1.29` added some nice functionality for listing the references in the sidebar.  See [references view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_references-view).

`List All References` in the context menu or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

> Results are stable and individual results can be cleared, which is great if you use the view as a To Do list. You can use <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to navigate through results without taking your hands off the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Mark, you're right.  Although it now seems to be working. For some reason I wasn't getting that extra content you mention in that box. It would've been nice for Shift + F12 to have taken you straight to the file it refers to instead of that popup (as VS community does) but, I guess, it's perhaps a matter of taste. Maybe I'm yet to discover how to do it.

Answer (score 16):

**ALT + Left Arrow and ALT + Right Arrow** worked for me. VS code listed all shortcuts in pdf [keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf).
To see all keyboard shortcuts go to menu bar Help->Keyboard Shortcuts Reference. It will open pdf that contains all shortcuts.[image]

Comment: `alt` + `F12` on linux

Comment: These shortcuts will be changing with respect to versions and OS. In my Ubuntu System, with Version 1.60.2, 'Ctrl+Alt+-' did the job. So Better open the help page and verify.

Answer (score 13):

The *keyboard shortcut commands* are *Go Forward* and *Go Back*.

---

On Windows:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> ... navigate back

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> ... navigate forward

On Mac:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate forward

On Ubuntu Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> .., navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> ... navigate forward

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433087/13155046)

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> worked for me or `Go` menu and then `Back`.

Answer (score 9):

Try [goto-symbol-stack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=miconda.goto-symbol-stack).

This extension implements a stack tracking the positions **only** when the goto-definition is triggered by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, and allows the user go back to the reference using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. No annoying cursor movement in the stock navigation(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>).

Comment: This is the only correct answer! `Alt` + `←` is _not_ the inverse of `F12`! I often go to the definition of a symbol, have a look round, and then want to return to the start of my excursion _without_ visiting all the intermediate stops.

Answer (score 9):

For those using the VSCodeVim extension, it would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach is to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click shortcut, which will open the definition in a new pane to the right. This can then be closed with the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> key combination.

Answer (score 3):

Go to definition <kbd>F12</kbd>

Back to declaration <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: Only works properly if you only have a single use of the variable in sight!

Comment: this rocks. Thanks. Only this worked for me in 2024 Jan

Answer (score 2):

1.Go Definition - F12 or Right click and Click Go to Definition Option

2.Back to Reference - Alt + Left Arrow

Answer (score 1):

**Next :** Ctrl + F12

**Back :** Alt + LeftRow (<--)

For Windows is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Fix it by installing this JDK 8  to VSCode

Answer (score 0):

In Version: 1.62.3 under Ubuntu:
it's just `F12` again

it's bound to both:

- `Go to Definition`
  and
- `goToNextReference`

Answer (score 0):

For C++, with clangd extension, without intellisense I have:

- kept <kbd>F12</kbd> mapped to `Go to Definition`
- remapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to `Go to Declaration` (removed pre-existing mappings on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> which where not useful).

Note: with clangd extension <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> is mapped to `clangd: Switch Between Source/Header` which can also be useful.