# How I can make `ctrl + click` to go to definition in visual studio code editor for mac OS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How I can make `ctrl + click` to go to definition in visual studio code editor for mac OS? Now it is F12 which is using my mac for show desktop.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

First and foremost, please note that in VS Code for macOS, the familiar **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click** from Windows / Linux operating systems has been replaced with **<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click** (i.e.: "command + click"). Try that first before proceeding any further as that shortcut *should* work out of the box without any special modifications.

However, if the above still doesn't work for you then try fixing the problem by editing your `settings.json` file. To do that, press <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `settings json`, then click `Open Settings (JSON)`, and then do one of the following:

To use **<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click** as your "Go to definition" shortcut, ensure the following line exists in your JSON settings:

```
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "alt",
```

What this does is it explicitly sets VS Code's "add another cursor" shortcut to **<kbd>option</kbd> + click** (try it out for yourself!), thus freeing up **<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click** to be used for the "Go to definition" operation.

Conversely, to use **<kbd>option</kbd> + click** as your "Go to definition" shortcut instead, add:

```
"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
```

Note: the above line will actually set the "add another cursor" shortcut to **<kbd>⌘</kbd> + click** (not ***<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click***, as implied by the JSON value).

Comment: How about our windows Java?

Comment: I don't understand how this is accepted answer the question is about how to change cmd+click to go to definition, but this is just changing multiCursorModifier

Comment: @Saba because the default trigger for "editor.multiCursorModifier" is _also_ the default trigger for "goToDefinition". Thus changing the trigger for "editor.multiCursorModifier" allows the ctrl+click command to pass to the next available action which is "goToDefinition"

Comment: This answer is literally talking about something entirely different than what the question was, yet is upvoted and selected as the best answrer. LOL

Comment: No, this is in fact the correct answer but people should learn to read carefully. 'alt' MUST be selected so the ctrl + click is freed up so to speak. Indeed this solved it for me.

Answer (score 38):

Settings > User > **multiCursorModifier must be set to alt (default)**, so the ctrl/cmd will be available to go to definition.

Documentation:

> The modifier to be used to add multiple cursors with the mouse. The Go To Definition and Open Link mouse gestures will adapt such that they do not conflict with the multicursor modifier.

Comment: Do you have any link to share that can provide more details?

Comment: does this work for bash ?

Answer (score 7):

In gear icon/keyboard shortcuts, search for `f12` .
Right-click on the "Go to Definition" entry and chose "Remove Keybinding".
Note that will put a new entry at the end of your keybindings.json like:

```
{
    "key": "f12",
    "command": "-editor.action.goToDeclaration",
    "when": "editorHasDefinitionProvider && editorTextFocus && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
}
```

Note the "-" sign before the command, that removes that keybinding.
Now copy and paste that whole entry below it (with a comma at the end of the previous entry):

```
{
    "key": "f12",
    "command": "-editor.action.goToDeclaration",
    "when": "editorHasDefinitionProvider && editorTextFocus && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "editor.action.goToDeclaration",
    "when": "editorHasDefinitionProvider && editorTextFocus && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
}
```

Remove the minus sign and assign whatever keybinding you like.  Alternatively, go back to shortcuts file, search for "Go to Definiton" and click the pencil icon to use its interface to create a new keybinding.

Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> is used in many contexts so you might have an unexpected conflict using such a common keybinding.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I checked this in the settings

```
Settings > User > multiCursorModifier must be set to alt (default)
```

By default, it is set to `alt` only

**I just did right-click on VS code and quit and open it again to resolve the issue.**

Hope it may help someone!

Answer (score 2):

I found what turned off this feature.

Go to Settings and search for "ctrlCmd". There are two settings that overrode the command: *Editor: **Multi Cursor Modifier*** and *List: **Multi Select Modifier***. I turned both of these off because I don't use them, and I got my control-click to definition back.

I know those settings are useful to some. The default for both is alt-click. I presume an extension or an update changed something.

Comment: Only a mad man would do something like that

Comment: How did you turn them off? When I click the dropdown it forces me to choose either ctrlCmd or Alt, but no "off" option is present.

Comment: This might help: I had accidentally triggered the command "Toggle Multi-Cursor Modifier" through the the command panel and didn't realise that this made `Cmd` on my mac become a multi-cursor modifier (previously it was only `Alt`). Triggering the command again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me <kbd>Ctrl ^</kbd>+click / <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+click was **not working**, although <kbd>F12</kbd> was. 
So, tried with <kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+click, which **worked**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case cmd+click wasn't working when i was connected to a remote machine via remote ssh, but worked fine locally. Installing language extensions(C/C++ Extension Pack in my case) on a remote solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the settings and type "Source definition" and check this boxes to go to the definition directly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to .flowconfig file and change the required the version(it is the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

In my vscode, this problem is proved to be caused by some extensions. After removing one extension(I forget the name, should be related with vscode), it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with my python code though it was working fine with my JS code. I have to install **Python extension developed by Microsoft** & it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to visual studio code -> Click on extension(left of screen) -> update your language extension.

Eg. If you are using python, then install updated python extension there.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was, on MacOs, was to click on "disable all extensions" in Visual Studio code, then restart the app, then click on "enable all extensions" again, and open another workspace :)

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me is to run:

`# go mod vendor`

Then I can reach the definitions by clicking alt