# Go To Definition in angular html file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is it possible, maybe with an extension, to use Go To Definition (F12) when editing an html file of an Angular project?

Let's assume, in sample.html:

```html
<input matInput class="app-input" placeholder="InputName" [(ngModel)]="myNodel.name">

...

<button mat-mini-fab class="plus"
  (click)="myMethod()"
  <mat-icon>arrow_forward</mat-icon>
</button>
```

I would like to navigate to "myMethod() ..." in sample.ts, or navigate to the field of the model, to the line "name: string;" in my-model.ts, as the function normally works with .ts files.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can do this with the extension

**[`Angular Language Service extension for VS Code.`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)**

which has the feature

This extension provides a rich editing experience for Angular templates, both inline and external templates including:

Completions lists

AOT Diagnostic messages

Quick info

Go to definition

**[`Angular Language Service - A handy extension for angular developers`](http://sajeetharan.blogspot.com/2017/11/angular-language-service-handy.html)**

Comment: Testing right away...
And works like a charm... Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: after going to definition/ navigating to specific section, How to go back where we click? actually the ts file is opening in same file where we clicked. I mean how to go back to the same file or re-open?

Comment: @vbRocks Do you mean simple go back? Alt + <-

Comment: @gerleim Navigating page by ctrl+click on the namespace but Alt+ <- is not working though. Let me revise my question: after going to definition how to return back where i navigated from (file)?

Comment: @vbRocks I tested it in some scenarios, and  Alt+ <- does navigate back for me.
This is on windows, different OSs use different keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433087/35150

Comment: I click `F12` at the component name, (for example, `<myDropDown>` )  and cannot go to definition? Just show `No definition found for <myDropDown>`. is it okay?

Comment: It works using the `cmd + mouse click` on Mac as well

Comment: I have already had that extension but "go to definition" didn't work anyway. Extension reinstall helped for me.

Comment: Reinstalling the Angular Language Service extension and restarting VS Code fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension **angular2-switcher**

This is my favorite, i share for whom concern.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher

Answer (score 5):

you will need just one extension
[Angular Essentials by John Papa](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials)

by installing this your vscode shall become pro-angular editor

Comment: The Angular language service (part of this pack) is the extension in particular that enables this feature, and it is awesome- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/angular-language-service-for-visual-studio/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `strictTemplates: true` to the `tsconfig.json` file like so:

```
   ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
```