# keyboard shortcut for go back to last edited position in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate (move cursor) to the last edited position (like in all Jetbrains products with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Backspace`)?

The `CTRL`+`-` shortcut moves to the last position (not the last edited position), which is less useful for me.

i am using with
Visual Studio Code
JetBrains IDE Keymap for Visual Studio Code:

Visual Studio Code
Version 1.23.1
Commit d0182c3417d225529c6d5ad24b7572815d0de9ac
Datum 2018-05-10T17:11:17.614Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architektur x64

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212026/836330 for new navigation commands in vscode v1.65.  See that link for navigating to next/previous cursor locations (where the cursor was but maybe no actual edit there).

For last edited locations:

```
Go Forward in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigateForwardInEditLocations"

Go Back in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigateBackInEditLocations"

Go Previous in Edit Locations
"workbench.action.navigatePreviousInEditLocations"

Go to Last Edit Location
      // acts like a toggle between current and last edit location
"workbench.action.navigateToLastEditLocation"
```

> Associated context keys have been added to make assigning keybindings
> more powerful:
>
> - `canNavigateBackInNavigationLocations`: Whether it is possible to go back in navigation locations
> - `canNavigateForwardInNavigationLocations`: Whether it is possible to go forward in navigation locations
> - `canNavigateToLastNavigationLocation`: Whether it is possible to go to the last navigation location
> - `canNavigateBackInEditLocations`: Whether it is possible to go back in edit locations
> - `canNavigateForwardInEditLocations`: Whether it is possible to go forward in edit locations
> - `canNavigateToLastEditLocation`: Whether it is possible to go to the last edit location

Comment: that's much better than that was i was looking for

Comment: Cmd+K and Cmd+Q  for Mac, but I had to remap them because they were already  taken by OS.

Comment: If you use vim extension, I would recommend to chante the default keybinding for the  _Go to Last Edit Location_ command. Bind it with`Alt+Shift+J` instead. Go to _File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts_ or insert in _keybinds.json_  
`{ "key": "shift+alt+j",  "command": "workbench.action.navigateToLastEditLocation"}` to do it.

Comment: I made it to:  {
    "key": "cmd+shift+backspace",
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateToLastEditLocation"
  }, to align with Intellij

Comment: How to navigate to a **previous** edit location, not only to the last one?

Comment: All of these are not the same thing that exist in Intellij IDE's. In Intellij you can always move through last **N** locations, not only to the latest one.

Answer (score 35):

For Windows use `Alt+RightArrow` and `Alt+LeftArrow`.

Comment: Those are for workbench.action.navigateBack and forward not for navigating to last edit. Difference is that by navigating back you are steping trough each view you have visited. Whether to last edit you skip all visited views and jump directly to last edited location which is mostly much more desired :)

Comment: For MAC (Navigation):


```Ctrl+-```  navigate back


```Ctrl+Shift+-```  navigate forward

Comment: @SaurabhBayani you should add an answer I would totally upvote it. thanks

Comment: Alt+RightArrow/LeftArrow walkes open files, not to edit positions here in my Kubuntu v 20.04

Answer (score 4):

### Last Edited Shortcut

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>

[image]

### Last Cursor Movement

<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow left</kbd>

[image]