# In VS code: Go back to last edit location across all files

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Alt+Left only goes back to the last location in the same file. How can I configure it to go back to the last edit location across all of the files in the project?

Context: I have a multi-file project in LaTeX Workshop. Often I would like to jump to a location to see the code and then jump back to my previous location to continue editing.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in way to do that.  But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611031/836330.   And `Alt+Left` goes back to other files for me (not necessarily only edits in those files though).

Comment: Unless you mean to strictly go to the very last edit (not to the previous edits in order), then `Ctrl+K Ctrl+Q` will do that as in the linked answer.  In which case this question is a duplicate.