# Navigating back from go to definition in VSCode and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

When we right click and select `Go to definition` in VSCode, it opens the new file in place of the current.  How do we navigate back to where we came from?

Comment: it is possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424367/how-to-navigate-back-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 3):

On Windows:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> .. navigate back

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> .. navigate forward

On Mac:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate forward

On Ubuntu Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate back

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> .. navigate forward

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, it's `Alt+LeftArrow`, just like navigating backwards in a web browser.

Comment: Hmmm - That's the first thing I tried and it does not work on Ubuntu ...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize what OS you were on. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433087/226781

Comment: Also, in VS Code, take a look at File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. You can search there by command name (and also by key name, like LeftArrow, which  is handy).