# Prevent VS Code from moving cursor to beginning of file on Save As

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, anytime I `File > Save As`, the cursor will jump to the beginning of the file. This is undesired if I am trying to create many new files and only changing 1 small line or variable. Sublime and Atom keep the cursor in the same spot when performing a Save As. Is there anyway to keep the cursor in the same location on a Save As?

I have tried disabling all extensions and currently am not trimming trailing white space.  Bookmarks do not appear to work.  It would seem that VS Code treats the file after a Save As as a new file and removes all bookmarks.

Comment: VS Code closes the current file and opens the other saved-as file and brings it to focus on the editor. It gets treated like any other newly opened file with the cursor at the start. The only workaround is to [setup a navigate back key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35424367/2745495) to reopen your previous file at its previous cursor position.

Comment: Most other text editors (atom, sublime) do not behave this way

Answer (score 1):

An issue was posted on the VS Code GitHub repo on the same day that this quesiton was posted (just about 4 hours later!) here: [File > Save As moves cursor to beginning of file #77996](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77996).

The issue was fixed by commit [`222401c`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/222401c661559aa4d655f91181fda3f917c5d000).

[According to one of the maintainers, bpasero, this was a regression that went unnoticed for a while](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77996#issuecomment-518215922):

> Good catch, looks like this broke a while ago.