# Does Visual Studio Code have a 'back' button?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I `Cmd + click` on the line of execution of a function (`f()`), it takes me to where the function was defined (`f(){}`). It'd be great to have a 'back' button to go back to wherever I was before, now that I've finished looking at the function. Does anyone know of such a feature or a feature that'd help?

P.S. I'm on Mac

Comment: Use Menu -> Go -> Back/Forward. Keyboard shortcut is Control + '-' / Control + Shift + '-' (For mac)

Answer (score 44):

In Windows VS Code, you can right-click on the toolbar > tick 'Command Center' and the back and forward buttons appear.

Edit:
This works for mac too.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ElhD.png)

Comment: I just tried it on Mac and it works, too. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, thanks for feeding that back. Updated my response to reflect :-)

Comment: This should be enabled by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

It's not a *button*, but there's a keyboard shortcut: press alt + left arrow, and you'll be taken to the place where you were before. (Browsers and Windows Explorer have this shortcut too - alt + left arrow usually takes you to the previous page, but they also have back buttons)

Comment: Pressing `option + left-arrow` just moves the cursor but Stefan Wang's suggestion worked

Answer (score 10):

You're far from alone in missing the "go back" button (that I missed from Visual Studio).  Here is one of multiple available VS Code plugins which provides *just* what you're missing:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nick-rudenko.back-n-forth

You can find other plugins with search for "back button".

Comment: seriously. What is the purpose of being different if no on likes it. IDEs need to stick to sane defaults.

Comment: @ThisCompSciGuy  This is the reason vs cod is so great.  It is a completely barebones IDE that is configurable to almost anything.  You want a back button? Download this extension.  You need C# code analyzers?  Download one of these five extensions.

Comment: I like this one better  
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Scotthew.go-nav-bar  
It has a few other nice options too

Comment: @JSON All IDEs support extensions/plugins with few exception. That isn't a feature that sets VS Code apart. What I disagree with is that VS Code requires an extension for something as fundamental as GUI navigation controls that is universal to all other IDEs and all programming languages. If I wanted to use only keyboard short cuts for the basics, I would stick with VIM, which supports plugins, and has much more powerful keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @ThisCompSciGuy Sure, but other IDEs are clunky coming packed full of default functionality and are much less efficient because of it.  VS code is lightweight and configurable to handle almost anything other IDEs can.  For example, regular Visual Studio takes about 5 minutes to load and eats upwards to 3 GB of ram at times.  VS code barely scratches 1 GB and boots up in seconds.

Answer (score 7):

Most voted answer didn't work for me, there is no option to enable the `Command Center` by right-clicking on the toolbar as the screenshot shows.

What worked was to change my settings file to add

```json
// This goes in your Default profile's settings file
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",

// This goes in your current profile's settings file
"window.commandCenter": true
```

`window.titleBarStyle` is by default applied to all profiles and should be placed in de `Default`'s settings file. However you can choose to enable or disable `window.commandCenter` for each of your profile by setting it to `true` or `false` in all your profiles' settings files.

Alternatively, if you're not used to modify your settings files directly you can use the UI setttings.

1. Open your settings (`Ctrl` + `,`)
2. Search for `Command Center`
3. Tick the `Window: Command Center` checkbox
   [image]
4. Click on the `Window: Title Bar Style` link
5. Set the `Title Bar Style` to `custom`
   [image]

Comment: I had the settings set like that and still don't see back and forward buttons.

Comment: So I apologize, I see the arrows, but they reworked the location since the last time when extensions provided it. It was in the status bar. Providing the screenshot with the arrows would help a lot.

Answer (score 6):

MacOS has `Command Center`, which can include back and forward buttons.

To activate, right click the top bar and select `Command Center`.  If you do not see left and right arrows, right click the search field in the middle of the Command Center bar and select `Go Back` and `Go Forward`.

Answer (score 5):

As of v1.68 I think, if you enable the `Command Center` in vscode with this setting:

```
Window: Experimental Command Center
```

and just

```
Window: Command Center
```

(note no "Experimental") in Insiders v1.69 and presumably Stable v1.69 you will get a left and right arrow in the title bar which are bound to the `Go Back` and `Go Forward` commands <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

Comment: this should be the selected right answer :)

Comment: I don't have this option.

Comment: @LukasSalich Did you look in your Settings UI for "Command Center"?  It is right there.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, they redesigned it and I did not see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371779/does-visual-studio-code-have-a-back-button/72820447?noredirect=1#comment136201668_76750931

Answer (score 2):

You can use `workbench.action.navigateBack` my keyboard shortcut defaulted to Ctrl+Alt+- for Back and Ctrl+Shift+- for forward

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a keybinding do exactly what you want. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> to go to a function definition and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd> to come back to where you were. Add the below snipped to `keybinding.json` file. `"key"` could be anything you want of course.

```js
    {
        "key": "ctrl ctrl",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack",
        "when": "!terminalFocus"
    },
```

Alternatively, if you have mouse with a `forward` and `backward` buttons, clicking on `backward` does exactly that by default. Tested on mx master mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I have a logitech mouse and using the Options+ software they provide I was able to "Add application". This provides custom settings for the mouse and a particular application. It comes pre-configured for apps like Chrome, Edge, Office, etc. I added Visual Studio Code and now I have both forward and back buttons working in Visual Studio Code (finally!).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Option+ app is so broken that it stops capturing any key besides "Ctrl", so the back/forward buttons stop working. Even worst, when I click it inserts the keys in the code instead of activating the shortcut. The worst experience with the mouse and keyboard I ever had.

Answer (score 1):

1. On older versions you need to add an extention with the name Back<>Front
2. Off late from/back buttons are already inbuild and you can enable it by
   right click on top ribbon and check command center

(2) Is my preferred way as the button appear at the mid of rioon which is most convenient.

[Screenshort of Visual Studio Code showing where to click and how the buttons appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49fkT.png)