# vscode: Keep the cursor on the *last* instance when escaping from multiple cursors (cmd-d)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use multiple cursors in VSCode (`cmd-d`/`ctrl-d`) a lot.

To quit the multiple cursors mode and go to normal single-cursor mode, you can use `esc`.

However, this will move the cursor back to the *first* selected word.
I want the cursor to stay at the *last* selected word.

Is there a shortcut / a setting to do that?

Example:

```
L01   foobar = 42
...
L99   foobar = 99
```

When I start in L01, `ctrl-d` on foobar, `ctrl-d` again I have multiple cursor on L01 and L99. After `esc` I will have single cursor back on L01. I want to have single cursor on L99.

Note: [How to navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424367/how-to-navigate-back-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-visual-studio-code) does not help in my case (it doesn't work for multiple cursors)

Comment: See (and upvote) the same issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88275  On the Backlog for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.3.1 and the command `moveby.calculation` you can calculate the new location of the cursor. By using the collapse feature of VSC you are left with 1 cursor.

Define this keybinding

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i escape",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "args": {
      "lineNrEx": "selections[selections.length-1].start.line",
      "charNrEx": "selections[selections.length-1].start.character"
    }
  }
```