# VS Code shortcut to return to cursor position before search

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, after I've used the "Find" function (`Ctrl+F` on Windows, `Cmd+F` on Mac), how I do return to the cursor position I was at when I started the search?

If I disable incremental search (`editor.find.cursorMoveOnType`), I can use the "Go Back" shortcut to do this – see question [How can I navigate back to the last cursor position in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424367/how-can-i-navigate-back-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-visual-studio-code). But if I keep incremental search enabled, pressing "Go Back" doesn't work properly. (It repeatedly moves me through the partial matches character by character, and then it doesn't always jump to the beginning of the search, but rather some earlier cursor position.) Is there some shortcut or command that still works with incremental search?

Comment: Isn't it just that you need to invoke the "go back" action more times? It seems that for each state of the find input as you type, if there's any possible match, the caret will jump to that match (if `editor.find.cursorMoveOnType` is `true`), and each jump will create a location history entry (not sure what the official terminology is. (not sure if it's officially called a "location history entry")). So you just need to invoke the "Go Back" action the number of incremental matches were found. Maybe annoying, but I'm not sure if there's better. Would that be satisfactory to you as an answer?

Comment: @user No, that's not what I'm looking for -- I find it too cumbersome to go character-by-character, and as I noted, it also doesn't seem to always jump to the place where you started the search, but rather some earlier cursor position.